# How to create an endpoint using the model trained by Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

I trained a model using Google Cloud Vertex AI. I have a dataset containing different videos and model does the video classification of these videos. In the Google Cloud Platform, I can find accuracy of the given videos after model has been trained. However, I could not find a way to create an Endpoint which is required to implement my model to the project.

In other words, I have a model trained by Google Cloud’s Vertex AI and I want to create an Endpoint which accepts a request with video and returns the accuracy according to the trained model. Google Cloud provides a way to do it using Endpoints but as shown below, following
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BgTG.png) occurs.
`This model cannot be deployed to an Endpoint`

I could not find any documents on why this error is given to me. On the other hand, when I download the given model, code requires input type as below with the video;

“`RESNETISH_V3: float32 Tensor, shape=(None, 128)`”.

I do not know what is this variable type and this is basically where I am stuck. I need help deploying my trained model to any serverless environment, create a code handling posted video and return the accuracy and class of the given video to the request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with an object tracking model. It looks like there is no Endpoint for models dealing with videos. But yes the documentation is horrible and this isn't specified in any way.